# Как подключиться по ssh без пароля?

Tags: ssh, linux

Всякий раз, когда я выполняю команду

```
ssh user@host
```

меня просят ввести пароль. Как избежать этого?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это можно сделать, используя публичные ключи. На примере OpenSSH. Предположим, нужно войти с хоста X на хост Y. Заходим на хост X и создаем ключи:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Далее заходим на хост Y и создаем папку `~/.ssh`

```
ssh user@Y mkdir ~/.ssh
```

Копируем публичный ключ с хоста X на Y

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@Y 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

После этого по ssh можно входить с хоста X на Y без пароля.

**Обновление**

В комментариях [@AntonioK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177853/antoniok) рекомендует не использовать `cat` для копирования публичного ключа. Вместо этого следует воспользоваться специальной утилитой `ssh-copy-id`, которая, помимо прочего, заботится о верном уровне доступа к ключам.

Comment: не надо копировать публичный ключ через `cat`, для этого есть специальная утилита `ssh-copy-id`, которая, помимо прочего, заботится о правильных permissions

Comment: @AntonioK Спасибо за пояснения! Обновил ответ.

Comment: Имхо, все равно будут копипастить путь через ssh & cat. Можно заменю полностью на метод с `ssh-copy-id`?

Answer (score 2):

генерируем ключ на хосте X

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

затем набираем

```
ssh-copy-id user@Y
```

удаленный хост вместо Y

Answer (score 0):

Задать пароль как ключ в командной строке (по умолчанию запрещено, объяснять, надеюсь, почему не надо?). А еще лучше - использовать вход по сертификатам (ключам).