# Разрешить доступ по ssh для пользователя ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Есть доступ по ssh публичным ключом к root, как сделать такой же доступ для другого пользователя?

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/338540/178576)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для другого *удалённого* (с точки зрения сервера) пользователя — добавить содержимое его ~/.ssh/id_*.pub (с клиентской машины) в /root/.ssh/authorized_keys ssh-сервера.

Для другого *локального* (с точки зрения сервера) пользователя — создать его, создать у него в домашнем каталоге каталог .ssh, а в нём — файл authorized_keys с содержимым из того же самого ~/.ssh/id_*.pub (с клиентской машины).

Для развёрнутых описаний посмотрите man ssh в части AUTHENTICATION и man ssh-copy-id.